# Rails websocket error err_empty response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye

I am trying to follow [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye)

But I am getting these errors

```
1) WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9292/faye' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Upgrade' header is missing
<br>
2) Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE <br> 
3) POST http://localhost:9292/faye net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
<br>
```

[application.html.erb]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

      <%= javascript_include_tag  "http://localhost:9292/faye.js" %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= yield(:head) %>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
      <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
        <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
      <% end %>
      <%= content_tag :h1, yield(:title) if show_title? %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

my rest jquery javascript are not loading